# Is this temperature and pressure release piping up to code?

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, hot-water, tankless, pressure

I just finished installing this Rennai natural gas tankless heater yesterday, and it's working well.

My only question is I'm wondering that if I ever get it inspected, will this T&P release piping pass? I've added a slight bend in the pipe in order to use a preexisting exit hole, but the slight "detour" the water has to make could be considered an obstruction.

I'm based in Texas, if that helps. I'm more concerned about safety honestly than the code, but they go hand in hand.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have a threaded end (that could be capped) there's nothing there to be an obstruction (of course, you could glue on a cap and obstruct it, but code doesn't get into that, normally. they do specify a plain end with no threads.) Simply having elbows is not an obstruction, though it does add some dynamic head .vs. a straight pipe.

In **my** area it would have to be metallic for at least the first 3 feet from the heater. That may not apply in **your** area. If it's used in ernest, water hotter than CPVC is rated for may be flowing through there. Many areas seem to think that's fine, though.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I was wondering about CPVC, given it's not rated that high.

Answer (score 1):

No…..only one 90 degree bend piped to within six inches above the floor.  Very specific in CT plumbing code

Comment: If I were to meet these guidelines, I would have to install a floor drain, correct? I'm assuming a bucket or drain pan doesn't qualify, even though I've seen plumbers do this before!

Comment: I’ve never seen a floor drain near a heating appliance.  This device is installed only to protect the equipment and hardly ever is it activated.  It’s purpose is to reduce the high pressure that may build up in the appliance

Comment: I see. It's interesting because the PRT valve that was actually included with the hot water heater actually has two 90 degree bends already in it, pointing it downwards.